# How to decrement and increment the autocheck in the checkbox based on the count which enter in the form field

Tags: angular

I have a requirement where, when i enter the count in the input form field , based on the number of count the checkbox in the table have to autocheck , im able to do it, but im unable to update it , if i reduce the count in the field , in the table the checkbox is unchecking based on the count but if i increase the count at that time the autocheck  for checkbox is not applying.

```
  addDamaged(id,index) {
    let damageCheckBoxes = this.damageCheckBoxes.toArray();
     this.materialList  = this.dataSource.data;
     if(this.materialList[index]['id'] ===id && this.damagelist.length < this.secondFormGroup.get('count').value 
        && this.secondFormGroup.controls['comment'].value && damageCheckBoxes[index].checked){
        this.materialList[index]['isDamage'] = true;        
        if(this.materialList[index]['isDamage']){
          this.materialList[index]['damage']= { comment :this.secondFormGroup.get('comment').value}; // add damge to meterial
          this.damagelist.push(this.materialList[index]); // update damage list with items
        }
        damageCheckBoxes[index].checked = true;
     } else{
        damageCheckBoxes[index].checked = false;
        this.materialList[index]['isDamage'] = false;
          delete this.materialList[index]['damage'];
          for (let dIndex in this.damagelist){
            if(this.damagelist[dIndex].id === this.materialList[index]['id']){
              this.damagelist.splice(dIndex,1);
            }
          }
     }
     this.dataSource.data = this.materialList ;
  }


  checkDamage(){
    let damageCheckBoxes = this.damageCheckBoxes.toArray();
    this.materialList = this.dataSource.data;
    let count = this.secondFormGroup.get('count').value;
    for(let i = 0;i<count;i++){
      if(this.secondFormGroup.get('comment').value && this.damagelist.length<this.secondFormGroup.get('count').value ){
        this.materialList[i].damage = { comment :this.secondFormGroup.get('comment').value};
        this.damagelist.push(this.materialList[i]);
    //  console.log( this.materialList[i].damage);

      }
     else{
      damageCheckBoxes[i].checked = false;
      this.materialList.forEach(ele=>{
        ele.damage = null;
      })
      this.damagelist = [];
      if(this.secondFormGroup.get('comment').value){
        this.materialList[i].damage = { comment :this.secondFormGroup.get('comment').value};
        damageCheckBoxes[i].checked=true;
        this.damagelist.push(this.materialList[i]);
        console.log( this.damagelist);
      }

   /*   for (let dIndex in this.damagelist){
        if(this.damagelist[dIndex].id === this.materialList[i]['id']){
          this.damagelist.splice(dIndex,i);
        }
      }
    */
    }
    }


   }
```

In the code the addDamage method is used for the checking and unchecking manually based on the count.
The checkdamage method is used for the autocheck based on the count.If i reduce the count it is unchecking its fine but if i increase the count it is checking the checkbox based on the count Can anyone help to solve this

Comment: how is this angular, if anything it looks like javascript

Comment: @BlackICE, sry but its angular only ,Used the angular material also  you can see that im used the datasource to display the data in the mat-table.